# Run Mocha tests automatically on each source file change

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, package.json

What is the simplest way to tell Mocha to watch for source project files changes so that it can re-runs its tests?

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run with the [watch flag](https://mochajs.org/#-w---watch)

```
mocha -w ./tests
```

And, if your test folder is called just `test/` then you don't need to point out the folder (Mocha looks for changes in such folder by default), so you can end up just with:

```
mocha -w
```

Comment: this watches for test files changes, isn't it? I would like Mocha to observe my `./src/**` files and, on each change, re-run the tests

Comment: @jbarros the watch flag listens for changes in the CWD so as long as your source directory is included in that it'll re-run on changes to source code as well as tests. The file path dictates where mocha will find the test files in relation to the CWD.

Comment: thanks for your response. But I don't want my `src` code inside `test` folder.

Comment: @jbarros you don't have to, the CWD is determined by the terminal or whatever environment the CLI is executed under e.g. if your directory structure is `./src` and `./test` then the above should work exactly as you want because the CWD is `.`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks :-)

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion. './test' here only points to your test folder and has nothing to do with the watching feature per se.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm running NodeJS in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely do not recommend mocha watch function for the following reasons:

- The file watcher does not work properly;
- It is not compatible with ES modules;

To solve this, I did the following changes on my project:

- Install nodemom: `npm install nodemon --save-dev`;
- Install mocha, if not have it: `npm install mocha --save-dev`;
- Execute this command in your terminal changing the `./test` to point to your test folder: `./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --watch . --exec 'mocha ./test || true'`;
- You can also put this command inside the `scripts.test` section in the file `package.json` to make you life easy;

References:

- https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/496#issuecomment-325150315

Answer (score 1):

The watch mode is mocha is gonna complain about the `required()` if your applications type is module.

```json
"type": "module",
```

The safe way is to use nodemon instead which will keep an eye on changes in all files and rerun every time there is a change
in `package.json` set under scripts :

```json
    "test": "nodemon  --exec npx mocha || true",
```

Now `npm run test` will take care of the requirement.